# Is it possible to use std::visit on variant that hold same type more than once?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, std-variant

For example, I'm trying to implement an AST using `std::variant`, where a Token can be a number, keyword, or variable. Where numbers are represented by the `int` and keywords and variables are represented by `std::string`:

```cpp
enum TokenType : std::size_t {
    Number = 0, Keyword = 1, Variable = 2,
};
using Token = std::variant<int, std::string, std::string>;
Token token(std::in_place_index<TokenType::Variable>, "x");
```

When I want to do something with `token`, I can first determine its type with `token.index()` and then decide what to do:

```cpp
switch (token.index()) {
case TokenType::Number:
    return do_sth_with_number(std::get<TokenType::Number>(token));
case TokenType::Keyword:
    return do_sth_with_keyword(std::get<TokenType::Keyword>(token));
case TokenType::Variable:
    return do_sth_with_variable(std::get<TokenType::Variable>(token));
}
```

However, I don't know if I can use `std::visit` to achieve the same effect. I only know that it can call specific function depending on the type of data in the variant, but I don't know if it is possible to do this depending on the index.

I know I can accomplish my goal by wrapping Keyword and Variable in two different classes, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it, because as I understand it, in variant, it should be more straightforward to decide which function to use based on the index rather than the type.

Comment: The cleanest design is to have each kind of Token being represented by its own type and get rid of the `TokenType` enum altogether. The type of the token is the alternative held by the variant. No reason to save that same information in two different places.

Comment: Why not use an altetered version of `std::visit`? One that forwards index and the variable.

Comment: Yes, `std::visit` dispatches the call based on the index but in all cases it calls the same visitor. So no, you cannot use `std::visit` if the visitor depends on the index, not just type.

Comment: outside of generic code you shouldnt end up with two identical types in the variant to begin with. Make the type system your friend rather than fighting it and use a `std::variant<Number, Keyword, Variable>`

Comment: @ALX23z can you elaborate?

Comment: @MarekR write an alternative version to `std::visit` that calls `foo(index, var)` or `foo<index>(var)` rather than `foo(var)`. The implementation is pretty much the same as `std::visit`, one just needs to forward the index in addition.

Comment: @ALX23z you've missed the point and just repleted same thing with more words. Where this is documented? Can you show demo on compiler explorer?

Comment: @MarekR "elaborate" is for explain better. I had no intentions to write an implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to dispatch different functions based on the `variant`'s index rather than the alternative type.

You can make the visitor accept an additional index constant to capture the index information of the current alternative, and then create a function table based on the size of the `variant` to forward different index constants and corresponding alternatives to the visitor

```
template<class Visitor, class Variant>
constexpr decltype(auto)
visit_i(Visitor&& vis, Variant&& var) {
  constexpr auto N = std::variant_size_v<std::remove_cvref_t<Variant>>;
  constexpr auto func_ptrs = []<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return std::array{
      +[](Visitor& vis, Variant& var) -> decltype(auto) {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Visitor>(vis), 
                           std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{}, 
                           std::get<Is>(std::forward<Variant>(var)));
      }...
    };
  }(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
  return func_ptrs[var.index()](vis, var);
}
```

Then you can visit the `variant` with a custom visitor that accepts an index constant

```
enum TokenType : std::size_t {
  Number = 0, Keyword = 1, Variable = 2,
};

using Token = std::variant<int, std::string, std::string>;

void do_sth_with_number(int);
void do_sth_with_keyword(std::string);
void do_sth_with_variable(std::string);

auto visitor = [](auto index, auto&& token) {
  if constexpr (index == TokenType::Number)
    return do_sth_with_number(token);
  else if constexpr (index == TokenType::Keyword)
    return do_sth_with_keyword(token);
  else if constexpr (index == TokenType::Variable)
    return do_sth_with_variable(token);
};

int main() {
  Token token(std::in_place_index<TokenType::Variable>, "x");
  visit_i(visitor, token);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3n19Mf9eW)

Answer (score 1):

IMO there is no need to make things over-complicated:

```cpp
void foo(const MyVariant& v)
{
    auto index = v.index();
    std::visit([index](const auto& x) {
        std::cout << "Index: " << index << " value: " << x << '\n';
    }, v);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/EfET9s97c

but IMHO comment under question from ComicSansMS is best solution.